# Which tense is it the most natural to use when you describe something that happens in a recording?

Tags: past-simple, present-simple, past-continuous

Which tense is it the most natural to use when you describe something that happens in audio: the present simple, past simple, or past continuous. For example:

> We are going to listen to a recording, and what you'll have to do is to tell me who **calls** who in it.
>
> We are going to listen to a recording, and what you'll have to do is to tell me who **is calling** who in it.
>
> We are going to listen to a recording, and what you'll have to do is to tell me who **was calling** who in it.

Comment: We don't say "an audio" - *audio* is an adjective.   We'd say "listen to a recording."

Comment: I would consider the second the most natural and the third the least (the conversation took place in the past, but we speak of the content of a recording in the present tense).

Comment: You can see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290018/should-i-describe-a-book-ive-read-in-the-past-or-present-tense) about describing the events in the plot of a book, where the consensus is that present tense is simpler and normal with fiction, but for history you might use past. If you emphasise the fact that it happened in the past, it makes sense to use past tense.

Comment: There's also a question, somewhere, about describing a photo.  I think the advice there is that "you can use either tense" and that is also true here.

Comment: Depends. If a person is going through a process of calling someone throughout the recording, i.e., trying to find their phone, looking up the number, or experiencing any number of obstacles in the process, use "is calling." Otherwise, "calls". "was calling" and "called", respectively, also work, but are less colloquial.